# Moving a bounty to a different question

Tags: discussion, support

I've accidentally placed a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179182/creating-a-custom-filter-for-ng-repeat). However, I intended to place a bounty, instead, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411695/filtering-in-an-ng-repeat-from-json-response).

What, if anything, am I able to do to rectify this? I assume that it's not possible to move the bounty to a different question; so what's the correct course of action here to not cancel the bounty but move it to the desired question?

Comment: Yeah but instead of canceling, here, it's about moving the bounty, which seem legit to me as long as no one answered

Comment: @Tom My question is explicitly about moving the bounty from one question to another. Not just cancel the first and lose another amount of reputation by adding a bounty to the intended question. So in this case i think there is a valuable difference

Comment: Why so? If your bounty is cancelled and your rep is refunded, you are free to place the bounty wherever you want. What else do you need?

Comment: I've cancelled the bounty. Be more careful in future!

Comment: @yivi First of all, the bounty being cancelled can only be done by moderators or higher classed users. So asking them to do this each time someone would make a simillair mistake like mine wouldn't be a nice solution since it isn't their job to only justify our mistakes. Secondly i think that "just doing" a solution like yours in massive reproduction would be bad for the community.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you! and i will! (:

Comment: I don't understand what you said. But as you see, the solution was ask to cancel the bounty, nothing else needed. If a moderator sees fit to cancel your bounty, you are good to go.

Comment: Allowing everyone to move around is obviously not possible at the moment, thus your question seeking the current way of handling that situation is a dupe of the linked question. If you want a different behaviour, then create a feature request.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the clarification, I will take a look at that section